# How to seperate my code to different php file?

Tags: javascript, php, json, flot

I have code that draws a plot using flot library. The data for plot is in my local database.

In one file there are php, javascript and html code. How can I seperate the php code to different file, that there would be left just html and javascript.

The code looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
    <?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";  
    $database = "testing";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$database);

    $query = "SELECT longLocation, latLocation FROM coords";
    $result = $connection->query($query);   

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($row['longLocation'],$row['latLocation']);
    }

   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
   var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>;
   $.plot("#placeholder", [ dataset1 ]);
   });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: You can start by using a template engine. Or do a asynchronous call to the script. Or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of all php code in the file you need to use AJAX. You would end up with 2 files, one containing the html and PHP file which would print out the json encoded data.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $.getJSON('get_data.php', {}, function (data) {
        $.plot("#placeholder", [ data ]);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

get_data.php:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";  
$database = "testing";
$connection = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$database);

$query = "SELECT longLocation, latLocation FROM coords";
$result = $connection->query($query);   

$dataset = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $dataset[] = array($row['longLocation'],$row['latLocation']);
}

echo json_encode($dataset);
```